# model.add( Dropout(0.25)) SyntaxError: invalid syntax in CNN

Tags: machine-learning, model, conv-neural-network

I am trying to do a CNN based project. But when I want to build a CNN model, I got an error in "model.add(Dropout(0.25))" in line 14. In the previous model.add(Dropout(0.25)) , i did not get error in line 9.
Can anyone tell me what is the problem here? Why does it give an error?

```
 model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32 , kernel_size=(3,3), acitvation ='relu' , padding='same' , input_shape = (28,28,1)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu' , padding='same'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2) ,strides=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(64,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu' , padding='same'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=2,padding='valid')
model.add( Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(512,activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Dense(1024,activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))             

model.add(Dense(10,activation='softmax'))
```

and the error message is

```
 File "<ipython-input-53-e1c5cf3b08b4>", line 14
    model.add( Dropout(0.25))
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to give the bracket on the line above. Just put the bracket at the end of line 13.

```
 model = Sequential()
    
    model.add(Conv2D(32 , kernel_size=(3,3), acitvation ='relu' , padding='same' , input_shape = (28,28,1)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    
    model.add(Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu' , padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2) ,strides=2))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    
    model.add(Conv2D(64,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu' , padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=2,padding='valid'))
    model.add( Dropout(0.25))
    
    model.add(Flatten())
    
    model.add(Dense(512,activation='relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    
    model.add(Dense(1024,activation='relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))             
    
    model.add(Dense(10,activation='softmax'))
```

Answer (score 4):

You forgot one parenthesis on the line above. Fix that and you are good to go, I believe.